# float left or auto margin if smaller then min-width

Tags: css

This wraps my div boxes in 2 columns

```
.box {
   float:left;
   height: 300px;
   min-width: 800px;
   width:50%;
   margin: 0px auto; /* <= do this when smaller then 800px ? */
}
```

But how can I tell the browser to center the boxes (`margin: 0px auto;`) when only one column of boxes fit on the screen width. Now the box is aligned to the left of the screen.

Comment: Use `@media` queries: read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries), [here](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) and [here](http://cssmediaqueries.com/).

Comment: you could do it by use `@media` queries like this demo - http://jsfiddle.net/68fn0kt0/1/

Comment: Terry, media queries could do the trick I think, thanks. Mary, I don't see any changes in the code?

Comment: @GertCuykens sorry I forgot to save the fiddle try this - http://jsfiddle.net/68fn0kt0/1/ (resize the browser and background will be red only for max-width 800px)

Comment: Ok thanks, don't know who was first, anyway media queries is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not entirely clear what you want.

You can use media queries to handle different screen width states:

```
@media all and (max-width: 799px) {

    .box {
        float: left;
    }

}

@media all and  (min-width: 800px) {

    .box {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You already had it not working with `float:left` for two or one.

Here the code that works:

**HTML**

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
    display:inline-block;     
    height: 300px;
    min-width: 800px;
    width:50%;
    background:yellow;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE.**](http://jsfiddle.net/68fn0kt0/4/)

The `text-align:center` you need on the parent element, since `margin:0 auto` does not work for `inline-block` elements.

Comment: This does only center and does not put the boxes next to each other when there is enough space.

Comment: For me it does, Firefox and Chrome?!?

Comment: You are right I did not make the screen big enough sorry :)

Comment: %)P Eazy. If you want to get rid of the `margin`s: http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/. (Y)

Comment: A one more thing my squares fil up the screen when there are next to each other `width:50%;` as intended.

Comment: Ah yeah, cool. Was not sure if I see the result then in JSFIDDLE. I will edit.

Comment: I tried it but as far as I can tell this only works for when width is fixed. (200px for example)

Comment: It does work, but only when you take care about the `margin`s, see link above. http://jsfiddle.net/68fn0kt0/4/.

Comment: The fiddle does indeed work, need some time to figure out why it does not work in my polymer element, thanks.

Comment: Ps can you change the fiddle in your answer please with the one in your comment? The last one is more correct for this question :)

Comment: You are welcome. Polymer, gotta look into that!! Fiddle changed.

Comment: Definitely, abstracting code blocks into elements makes your site so much more maintainable and easier to work on.

Comment: Do you have a link for "Polymer 101"? %)P

Comment: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-tutorial put the files on any  http server, just html and js it works out of the box. Look at the directory named finish. You can skip step 1 2 3 Very straight forward.